# Horizontal scroll css?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to have one `<div>` with id that has horizontal scroll, but the problem is it has to be responsive, not with fixed width.

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#myWorkContent{
    width:530px;
    height:210px;
    border: 13px solid #bed5cd;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#myWorkContent a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#myWorkContent img {border: 0;}
```

```
<div id="myWorkContent">
     <a href="assets/work/1.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200/" height="190"></a>
     <a href="assets/work/2.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120/"/></a>
     <a href="assets/work/3.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/90/90/" height="90" width="90"></a>
     <a href="assets/work/4.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50/" height="190"></a>
     <a href="assets/work/5.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100/"></a>
     <a href="assets/work/6.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200/" height="190"></a>
</div><!-- end myWorkContent -->
```

Thanks to http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/FPBWr/

The problem is with that 530px. I would like to use 100% instead. But then I got page scroll and scroll of the DIV goes right, can not get it, any idea?

Here is article in Serbian about solution
http://www.blog.play2web.com/index.php?id=18

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just set your width to auto:

```
#myWorkContent{
    width: auto;
    height:210px;
    border: 13px solid #bed5cd;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This way your div can be as wide as possible, so you can add as many kitty images as possible ;3

Your div's width will expand based on the child elements it contains.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPBWr/162/)**

Comment: +1. The problem was the DIV's border added to the 100%. "auto" is the right way to do it.

Comment: It depends. `width: auto;` will adjust to less than 100% if there is not enough content. If he wants it to **always** be 100% width, he should set the `box-sizing` property, as per my response below.

Answer (score 12):

Below worked for me.

Height & width are taken to show that, if you 2 such children, it will scroll horizontally, since height of child is greater than height of parent scroll vertically.

Parent CSS:

```
.divParentClass {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Children CSS:

```
.divChildClass {
    width: 110px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To scroll horizontally only:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

To scroll vertically only:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your `#myWorkContent`.

http://jsfiddle.net/FPBWr/160/

Comment: On this example, I'd replace the `height:210px;` with `height:auto;` as well, so that the pictures wouldnt get cut off.

Answer (score 0):

use max-width instead of width

`max-width:530px;`

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/FPBWr/161/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it this way:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
body { height: 100%; white-space: nowrap }
html { height: 100% }

.red { background: red }
.blue { background: blue }
.yellow { background: yellow }

.header { width: 100%; height: 10%; position: fixed }
.wrapper { width: 1000%; height: 100%; background: green }
.page { width: 10%; height: 100%; float: left }

<div class="header red"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page yellow"></div>
    <div class="page blue"></div>
    <div class="page yellow"></div>
    <div class="page blue"></div>
    <div class="page yellow"></div>
    <div class="page blue"></div>
    <div class="page yellow"></div>
    <div class="page blue"></div>
    <div class="page yellow"></div>
    <div class="page blue"></div>
</div>
```

I have the wrapper at 1000% and ten pages at 10% each. I set mine up to still have "pages" with each being 100% of the window (color coded). You can do eight pages with an 800% wrapper. I guess you can leave out the colors and have on continues page. I also set up a fixed header, but that's not necessary. Hope this helps.