# Keep child divs on one line?

Tags: css, html, parent-child

I've tried every suggestion I could find (most of them involving `white-space:nowrap` and `display:inline-block`) but so far nothing has worked to get these child *div*s to stay on one line and scroll horizontally.

### My code:

```
<div id="list">
    <a href="javascript:show('shown','id1','a1');"><div id="a1" class="inactive">link1</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a href="javascript:show('shown','id2','a2');"><div id="a2" class="inactive">link2</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a href="javascript:show('shown','id3','a3');"><div id="a3" class="inactive">link3</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a href="javascript:show('shown','id4','a4');"><div id="a4" class="inactive">link4</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a href="javascript:show('shown','id5','a5');"><div id="a5" class="inactive">link5</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a href="javascript:show('shown','id6','a6');"><div id="a6" class="inactive">link6</div></a>
</div>
```

Essentially this is a navigation bar for mobile devices that scrolls horizontally.

The normal version has this bar vertical (working fine) and the *"spacer"* div is used as a divider, switching from a horizontal rule to a vertical rule.

Comment: Please post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or additionally include relevant CSS used.

Comment: This post seems to have a solution to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256982/horizontal-scroll-css

Comment: Thanks for the replies all, here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JBDpr/
I discovered my issue though. I had spacer defined with "float:left" and after changing float to "none" it displayed properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `white-space: nowrap;`

http://jsfiddle.net/ySMdY/1/

```
#list {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#list a, #list a div, #list .spacer {
    display: inline-block;
}
#list a {
    /* just some styles so I can see it working */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 0 50px;
}
```

**ALSO**: IDs are supposed to unique per page. You can't have multiple `#spacer` `div`s, you should only have one. If you want multiple, `class` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! this almost works, however when I tried it my "spacer" divs now appear on the next line while everything else scrolls horizontally as it should.

Comment: @user3582362 we are missing your css rules to help you further . update your ids to class :)

Comment: @user3582362 did you update your `<div id="spacer">`s to `<div class="spacer">`, like I mentioned about multiple IDs? Also, as GCyrillus said, you could accomplish the spacing with `margin` on the `#list a` rather than adding superfluous elements.

Comment: This worked after setting "spacer" to "float:none" :) thanks for the help! The reason for "spacer" div is to have a visual line in between each of the links. That's why I chose not to use margin alone. http://jsfiddle.net/JBDpr/

Comment: In the way I'm using them, I don't see how it makes any difference if I define them with a class or id, since I want each of them to be EXACTLY the same anyway. I will most likely change it to a class though.

Comment: @user3582362 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute says "The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters." means to have more than one per page is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You have inline element and block elements together.

Set them all `display:inline-block;` and`white-space` will be efficient.

```
#list {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#list div ,
#list a {
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:normal;
  vertical-align:middle/* or else value*/
}
```

Comment: your div.spacer could be margins , pseudo element or an inline tag such as span.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to the other answers, I see no need to modify the children's CSS:

The only thing needed is making the list `flex` based, like so:

```css
#list {
  display: inline-flex;  
}

/* simulating your spacer */
#spacer { width: 10px; height:10px; }
```

```html
<div id="list">
    <a><div>link1</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a><div>link2</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a><div>link3</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a><div>link4</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a><div>link5</div></a>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <a><div>link6</div></a>
</div>
```