# echo the table and html code

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

Soo im trying to get the data of mysql base in tables, but its giving me errors

```
function content_temp()
{
    if(isset($_GET['action']))
    {
        if($_GET['action'] == 'bans')
        {
          echo " <table class='MYTABLE'>
          <div class="positiontable">
          <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>User</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>Time</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>IP</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=180>Reason</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>Admin</th>
                  </tr>
                  </div>
                  </table> ";

        echo " <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$name</td>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$time</td>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$ip</td>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=180>$reason</td>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$admin</td>
          </tr>";
        }
    }
}

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'positiontable' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\ucp\welcome.php on line 88
```

and this is css

```
CAPTION.MYTABLE
  {
     background-color:#33b061;
     color:33b061;
     border-width:1px;
  }

  TABLE.MYTABLE
  { 
     font-family:calibri;
     font-size:12pt;
     color:#000;
     background-color:#000000;
     width:650px;
     border-color:black;
     border-width:0.4px;
     opacity: 0.6;  }

  TH.MYTABLE
  {
     font-size:12pt;
     color:white;
     background-color:#33b061;  }


  TR.MYTABLE
  {  }

  TD.MYTABLE
  {  
     font-size:12pt;
     background-color:#FFFFFF
     color:white;
     text-align:center;  }
.positiontable
{
    padding: 180px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

and is there any way if it works that it only shows idk 10-15 fields and than it's scrollable, and yea, the table is going under mainarea, i cant select, copy or paste

```
echo '
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="toolbar" align="center">
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
                ',toolbar_temp(),'
            </div>
            <div id="upperimage">
        <div id="mainarea">' ,content_temp(), '</div>   
        </div>
    </div>';
?>

#mainarea {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    padding: 800px 100px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 700px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: "positiontable" should be 'positiontable'. fix the quotation marks and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using double quotes in div class which is creating problem ...so you need to use your class like this...

```
<div class="positiontable"> or <div class='positiontable'>.
```

Try This..

```
function content_temp()
{
    if(isset($_GET['action']))
    {
        if($_GET['action'] == 'bans')
        {
          echo " <table class='MYTABLE'>
          <div class='positiontable'>
          <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>User</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>Time</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>IP</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=180>Reason</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>Admin</th>
                  </tr>
                  </div>
                  </table> ";

        echo " <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$name</td>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$time</td>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$ip</td>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=180>$reason</td>
            <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$admin</td>
          </tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use this link to get scroll    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256982/horizontal-scroll-css

Comment: Thank you guys its not giving me errors, but now, this is, it's not displaying mysql tables

http://pastebin.com/9nd3yYu0

Comment: That Might be a different error....because I can't see any code related to MySQL table....please either post it in same question or ask new question

Answer (score 2):

Your `<div class="positiontable">` text in `function content_temp()` contains quotes which must be escaped  or replaced (as you're using quotes to specify the echo).

For example `<div class=\"positiontable\">` or `<div class='positiontable'>`.