# functions not showing tables

Tags: php, mysql, css, cookies

Soo this is giving me errors and idk why, table does exist but still not working, what did i do wrong ?

The content does show but still giving errors and not displaying what it should

```
function content_temp()
{
    if(isset($_GET['action']))
    {
        if($_GET['action'] == 'banlist')
        {
            echo " <div class='positiontable'>
          <table class='MYTABLE'>
          <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>User</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>Time</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=180>Reason</th>
                    <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>Admin</th>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  </div> ";

        $query ="SELECT * FROM `Banovi` LIMIT 5"; 
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        if($row)
            $name = $row['Ime'];
            $time = $row['Vreme'];
            $reason = $row['Razlog'];
            $admin = $row['Admin'];
            echo " <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
                <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$name</td>
                <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$time</td>
                <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=180>$reason</td>
                <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$admin</td>
              </tr>";           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Soooo what errors are you getting cuz wdk without a crystal ball.

Comment: What errors?  What is it showing that it shouldn't?

Comment: Print_r $row and also you are fetching 5 records from table and not using any loop

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);  you did not use mysqli_query to prepare your query.. check the tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: 1. It's not displaying data that it should from mysql base.
2. This errors: http://i.imgur.com/VO33eDu.jpg

Comment: You need to loop your database results to get the rows

Comment: **For A Kind Attention To All Of You** This User Has Asked Similar Question 2 Hours Before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156752/echo-the-table-and-html-code. He asked 7 questions Overall In Stack Overflow, And didn't accepted a single answer of us.

Comment: Who told u i didnt accept any of answers ? I am trying everything and accpeting all of your help, so what is your problem ? I've stated few times that i'm a newbie in all this so please stop whining. Again, i'm accepting all of the help im getting, but if i dont respond to every one of them it doesnt meen i didnt see it :S

Comment: **Adding to it** In this question, he used `echo " <div class='positiontable'>` which was `echo " <div class="positiontable">`. He got answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156752/echo-the-table-and-html-code and didn't bother to accept answer of that user who put his time and effort to correct his/her error and resolve his issues.

Comment: That is because the user before him posted solution and i got it fixed and didnt even open up a thread again after that :S

Comment: @Cadilab You might not know, but since youre new I will explain. What Nana means by _"accepting an answer"_ is that you havent clicked on the chekmark located next to the answers provided. When you do this, you are "accepting an answer".  Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh sorry but i didnt even know that button existed :S I will make sure to mark all of them :)

Comment: Yea i thought that was the issue.. People here can sometimes be anal. Excuse them.

Comment: is the function you provided a class method (_is it a class function_)?

Comment: Yeah no problem, thanks for making it clear for me :) And nana you could've explained it to me too, not starting an argument right away, i just registered to the forums, i cant know everything from the start ;)

Comment: Sorry for being Rude. No issue. Enjoy coding. *Cheers !!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

you might need do some changes:

```
function content_temp( $con ){
  if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    if($_GET['action'] == 'banlist'){
      echo " <div class='positiontable'>
        <table class='MYTABLE'>
          <thead>
            <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
              <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>User</th>
              <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>Time</th>
              <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=180>Reason</th>
              <th CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>Admin</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>";
          $query ="SELECT * FROM `Banovi` LIMIT 5"; 
          $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
          while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){

            $name = $row['Ime'];
            $time = $row['Vreme'];
            $reason = $row['Razlog'];
            $admin = $row['Admin'];
            echo "
              <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
                <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$name</td>
                <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$time</td>
                <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=180>$reason</td>
                <td CLASS='MYTABLE' height=40 width=80>$admin</td>
              </tr>";
          }?>
        </tbody>
      </table><?php           
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

In `content_temp( $con )`, the `$con` should be created and passed upon function call:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_database");
content_temp( $con );
```

Comment: Im getting this

http://i.imgur.com/w0qz5td.jpg

it says that con is not defined but on top of the script there is
`code` include("database.php");

and in that

<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","samp");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to the database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 die();
}

?>

Comment: Thank you im not getting any errors anymore, but also its not displaying the table anywhere :S

Comment: Thank you no errors ! :)
btw how can i make a loop through all mysql fields and get them all because it gets only the first one

Comment: Thank you, you helped me alot :)

Comment: U R welcome. please consider upvoting answers, to say thanks, instead of putting comments